# How to install MS Dynamics CRM 2013 on 2 tiers (App + DB)?

Tags: installation, dynamics-crm, multi-tier

I need to install MS Dynamics CRM 2013 on two tiers. I have two VMs and I want to install the database of the CRM on one instance and the app of the CRM on the other instance.

Kindly guide me how can this be done.

Regards,

F. Ali

Answer (score 1):

I'd start out by looking at the [Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Implementation Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40322) and then asking a more pointed question if you run into a problem. 
Here is the online version of the installation instructions: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699742(v=crm.6).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699742%28v=crm.6%29.aspx)

Install SQL Server on one VM and the CRM on the other, the installation will ask for the name of the SQL Server to use as part of the process.